# differentiability and linear operators

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

I could give suggestions for this question.

> $f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is differentiable in $a$, then for each  $ h \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ exists a linear transformation $B(h):\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $h \rightarrow B(h)$ is continuous in $h=0$ and $f(a+h)-f(a)=B(h).h$

I have difficulties to define the operator $B(h):\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$

thank you very much for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is differentiable at $x=a$, we can write $f(a+h) = f(a)+Df(a)h + r_a(h)$, where $r_a$ is $o(h)$.

Define $B(0) = Df(a)$ and $B(h) = Df(a) + r_a(h)\frac{h^T}{\|h\|^2}$ for $h \neq 0$, then we have $B(h)h = Df(a)+ r_a(h) = f(a+h)-f(a)$.

Since $\|B(h)-B(0)\| \le \frac{\|r_a(h)\|}{\|h\|}$, we see that $\lim_{h \to 0} B(h)=B(0)$, and so $B$ is continuous at $h=0$.

**Note**: If $f$ was $C^1$ we could write $f(a+h)-f(a) = \int_0^1 DF(a+th)h dt$,
and letting $B(h) = \int_0^1 DF(a+th) dt$ would do the trick.